# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{n} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^{n}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

**Conjecture:** Let $a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{n},b_{1},b_{2},...,b_{n}>0$ be such that

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\,&\geq\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}\,;\\
\sum_{i<j}a_{i}a_{j}\,&\geq\,\sum_{i<j}b_{i}b_{j}\,;\\
\sum_{i\neq j\neq k}a_{i}a_{j} a_{k}\,&\geq\,\sum_{i\neq j\neq k}b_{i}b_{j} b_{k}\,;\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}\,&=\,b_{1}b_{2}\cdots b_{n}\,.
\end{align*}$$

It follows that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{n} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^{n}$$

**Examples:**

- $n = 2$: $a_{1}+a_{2} \geq b_{1}+b_{2},a_{1}a_{2} = b_{1}b_{2}$ then $a_{1}^2+a_{2}^2\geq b_{1}^2+b_{2}^2$.
- $n = 3$: $a_{1}+a_{2} +a_{3} \geq b_{1}+b_{2} +b_{3} ,a_{1}a_{2}a_{3} = b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}$ then $a_{1}^3+a_{2}^3+a_{3}^3\geq b_{1}^3+b_{2}^3+b_{3}^3$.

**Note:** This is a repost of a question posted earlier today, that have been deleted by the author without reason. Since I put some-tough not too much-effort in the answer, I decided to repost it.

Comment: Not true for $n=3$.  If $a,b,c$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^3-6\,x^2+10.9\,x-6$, then $$a+b+c=6=1+2+3\,,$$ $$bc+ca+ab=10.9<11=2\cdot 3+3\cdot 1+1\cdot 2\,,$$ and $$abc=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\,,$$ but $$a^3+b^3+c^3=37.8>36=1^3+2^3+3^3\,.$$

Comment: This is not true even when the numbers are required to be integers.  The triples $(8,12,15)$ and $(9,10,16)$ provide a counterexample.

Comment: ah that's probably, why the author deleted it

Answer (score -2):

This can be proven easily by taking advantage of the AM-GM inequality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^n } \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}{b_i^n } \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^n } \geq n\cdot \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^{n}} |\cdot \frac{1}{n} \overset{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i^n } \geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{n}}$$

Comment: AM-GM isn't an "if and only iff" theorem.

Comment: ah this seemed to be too easy